# Azure Ad b2c msal Android

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

After updrading the dependencies of msal to `implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.2.+`  below error is getting

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

import com.microsoft.identity.client.MsalClientException;
^
symbol:   class MsalClientException
location: package com.microsoft.identity.client

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend opening an issue on [Microsoft MSAL for Android library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues) GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio click on `file` -> `Sync Project With Gradle Files`